# Why I'm unable to validate textFields in login Button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, uitextfield

I have given delegate to my all textfields but i am unable to validate if textfield is empty or not initially.. if i just put cursor in textfield, but without any text then i am able to check, then it says please enter PhoneNumber why?

if i didn't put cursor in textfield then access directly goes to else part, even all textfields are empty
here is my code, please help me in the code.

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    textField.text = ""
}
//MARK:- ButtonActions
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {

     if(userIdTextFielf.text?.isEmpty)!{
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter PhoneNumber", in: self)
    }
    else if(passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)!{
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter Password", in: self)
    }
    else if(passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)! && (userIdTextFielf.text?.isEmpty)! {
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter PhoneNumber & Password", in: self)
    }
    else{
        logInService()
    }
    }
```

Here is my loginservice:

```
 //MARK:- Service part
func logInService(){

    let parameters = ["username":Int(userIdTextFielf.text ?? "") as Any,
                      "imei_number":"test2012@gmail.com",
                      "password":passwordTextField.text as Any,
                      "name":"name"]

    let url = URL(string: "https://dev.com/webservices/login")
    var req =  URLRequest(url: url!)
    req.httpMethod = "POST"
    req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Contet-Type")
    req.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters as Any, options: .prettyPrinted) else {return}
    req.httpBody = httpBody
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: req, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if response != nil {
            // print(response)
        }
        if let data = data {
            do{

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
                print("the json of loginnnnnn \(json)")
                var loginStatus = json["status"] as? String
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if loginStatus == "Failed"
                    {
                       AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Invalid creadintials", in: self)
                    }
                    else{
                        self.Uid = json["id"] as? String
                        let emailL = json["user_email"] as? String
                        print("login uid \(self.Uid)")

                        KeychainWrapper.standard.set(emailL ?? "", forKey: "user_email")
                        let saveUserId: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(self.Uid!, forKey: "Uid")

                        let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let navigationController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeNavigation")
                        let appDelagate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                        appDelagate?.window??.rootViewController = navigationController
                    }
                }
            }catch{
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

if i click login button without phonenumber and password it always says `Invalid creadintials`

please help me in the code.

Comment: check userIdTextFielf have reference ?

Comment: @SGDev, no i have updated my post, please have a look and please help me in code

Comment: "else if(passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)! && (userIdTextFielf.text?.isEmpty)!" will never run, because if either are empty they will get caught by the if statements above

Comment: The simple way to diagnose this is to print the userid and password when you hit that `else` statement and see what they are. They’re obviously not empty. So what are they? Spaces? Some placeholder text? Make sure there aren’t default values there. Make sure someone didn’t accidentally put some placeholder text as the `text` rather than the `placeholder`.

Comment: @Rob, i have given text in textfield, enter userid.. like placeholder text.. thats why `(userIdTextFielf.text?.isEmpty)!` is not cosidering as a empty.... now how to validate thats my issue

Comment: Yep, that’s what I thought. The `UITextField` has a `placeholder` property for this. Don’t use `text` for that. Or if you’re going to do this “manual placeholder text in `text`” technique, then you have to check for both `!isEmpty` but also `!=` to the placeholder string.

Comment: @Rob, i want coloured text in textfield thats why i have given text in textfield... if i tap in userIdTextFielf.. it becomes empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would appear to be placing some placeholder string in the `text` property of the text field. Generally we wouldn’t do that. Put the placeholder string in the `placeholder` property of the text field and it will do precisely what you want, namely show the placeholder text if empty, otherwise show what the user entered. And then you don’t need that `textFieldDidBeginEditing` implementation and your simple `isEmpty` checks will work.

If you want to do your own manual placeholder process, using the `text` property, then you have to change your validation logic, checking for both `isEmpty` and that it’s not equal to your placeholder text.

For example, you might use a utility method to figure out what the user actually entered (i.e. if it’s equal to the default text string, then return zero length string):

```
@IBAction func didTapLogin(_ sender: Any) {
    let userid = actualInput(for: useridTextField, defaultText: "Enter userid")
    let password = actualInput(for: passwordTextField, defaultText: "Enter password")

    switch (userid.isEmpty, password.isEmpty) {
    case (true, true):
        AlertFun.showAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter PhoneNumber & Password", in: self)

    case (true, _):
        AlertFun.showAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter PhoneNumber", in: self)

    case (_, true):
        AlertFun.showAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter Password", in: self)

    default:
        logInService()
    }
}

func actualInput(for textField: UITextField, defaultText: String) -> String {
    let text = textField.text ?? ""
    if text == defaultText {
        return ""
    } else {
        return text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```

---

Personally, even if you’re using your custom placeholder in `text` trick, I might still store the placeholder string in the `placeholder` property to hold that. I might also move this to an extension of `UITextField`:

```
extension UITextField {
    var userInput: String? { text == placeholder ? "" : text }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var useridTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        useridTextField.placeholder = "Please enter userid"
        passwordTextField.placeholder = "Please enter password"

        useridTextField.text = useridTextField.placeholder
        passwordTextField.text = passwordTextField.placeholder
    }

    @IBAction func didTapLogin(_ sender: Any) {
        let userid = useridTextField.userInput ?? ""
        let password = passwordTextField.userInput ?? ""

        switch (userid.isEmpty, password.isEmpty) {
        case (true, true):
            AlertFun.showAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter PhoneNumber & Password", in: self)

        case (true, _):
            AlertFun.showAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter PhoneNumber", in: self)

        case (_, true):
            AlertFun.showAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter Password", in: self)

        default:
            logInService()
        }
    }

    func logInService() { ... }
}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.text == textField.placeholder {
            textField.text = ""
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {
        if textField.text?.isEmpty ?? true {
            textField.text = textField.placeholder
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you avoid sprinkling your code with string literals, even if the user taps on the field (where you remove the text), they can now see placeholder string so they know what to enter, etc.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, if it is placeholder string then i am able to validate, but i need colored text in textfields... thats why this issue, please tell me how to validate

Comment: @swift See example above.

Answer (score 0):

use `isEmpty` instead of equality with ""

Answer (score 0):

you can try this or above all solution

```
    if userIdTextFielf.text?.isEmptyOrWhitespace() ?? true
    {
         AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter PhoneNumber", in: self)
        return
    }
    else if passwordTextField.text?.isEmptyOrWhitespace() ?? true
    {
         AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter Password", in: self)
    return
    }

extension String {
func isEmptyOrWhitespace() -> Bool {
    if(self.isEmpty) {
        return true
    }
    return (self.trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespaces) == "")
}
```

Comment: use guard keyword instead of if condition.

Comment: hey, i just noticed that i have given userid and password in textfields as text not a placeholder text thats why i am unable to validate..

Comment: how to take userid as a empty text in textfield and validate